# High CPU utilization in WFE-w3wp.exe

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We have 2 Web Front End Servers-SharePoint Server 2010 farm and are configured using NLB.

From 2 weeks, there is a heavy load in WFE Server 1 alone.

Configuration of both the servers are the same.

How can we resolve this? Please help me on this.

Comment: Please ask only one question per issue. I've merged your duplicate questions for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the current HTTP requests by running:

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list requests

This may provide a better hint as to what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Check in Network Load Balancing that the web front ends are set to equal load.  The MS NLB may be sending all requests through to one WFE.

Also check if you can navigate to each WFE individually. You may have to add an alternate access mapping for this if you don't already ahve one.

Answer (score 0):

The w3wp worker process is generate per application pool. I would first check to make sure each of your Sharepoint web applications is on its own application pool and check to ensure each service application has its own application pool. In addition you can look in IIS to see what is running on that particular worker process to get an idea of what applications are causing the high CPU utilization.

Comment: This is one way to identify the app pool by the PID from task manager: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2009/10/22/which-w3wp-exe-pid-corresponds-to-which-application-pool.aspx

Comment: Generally you should not completely separate all Web App and SAs into individual App Pools (due to the 10 per server support limit).

Comment: Depending on individual web application and farm scenarios, for example a teams web app should be in a diff. process space to an apps web application.  You should separate when appropriate.

Comment: @TrevorSeward What do you mean by "10 per server support limit"?  I have servers with a lot more than 10 application pools...