# High CPU utilization-w3wp.exe

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [High CPU utilization in WFE-w3wp.exe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20828/high-cpu-utilization-in-wfe-w3wp-exe)

How can the high cpu utilization due to w3wp.exe in sharepoint 2010 servers can be resolved?

Please help me on this to overcome the issue.